# Function argument in R allows to omit dot

Tags: r

Assume the following simple function:

```r
test_function <- function(abc.def = 1){
  print(abc.def)
}
```

Trying the following examples, we can note that:

```r
> test_function ()
[1] 1
> test_function (abc.def = 3)
[1] 3
> test_function (abc = 2)
[1] 2
```

I'm interested in the call `test_function (abc = 2)`, which manages to guess that `abc` is `abc.def`.

**My question:** why does this work? Does this behaviour have a name (and, hopefully, some further documentation)? Is it possible to block/disable this?

*Unrelated note for context:* I've noticed in rare cases that this can be confusing for students, where in specific cases if a function expects an argument say `sigma.squared`, the function will work with just `sigma` passed instead. There, however, without reading the documention the user would guess that the squared term is accounted for, meanwhile in reality it seems to be some sort of base R behaviour.